# Development under Android

Tags: java, android

I have the Android-based tablet, and I want to do some development actions on it.

Is there a way to code and compile Java and Android applications on my tablet?

Comment: This may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/is-possible-install-eclipse-ide-in-honeycomb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to code and compile Java and Android applications on my tablet?

There is no supported edition of the Android SDK build chain that works on Android devices. You are welcome to type in your code on a tablet, if you are a complete glutton for punishment, but you will need to compile that code on a development machine.

I have no idea what "development actions" are. If you mean scripting, look at [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).